# Incorrect result of NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

Since I cannot contact [Wolfram support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback) , I  am posting a question at this forum.

`Mathemaica v: 13.2.1`

`OS: Windows 10`

```
    NSolve[6*Log[(Sqrt[2 x] + Sqrt[x + 1] + 4*Surd[x + 3, 4])/6] == 
    Log[x + 3] + Log[Sqrt[2 x^2 + 2 x]] && x >= 0 && x <= 10, x, Reals]
```

I obtain `{}` which is not true in view of:

```
    6*Log[(Sqrt[2 x] + Sqrt[x + 1] + 4*Surd[x + 3, 4])/6] == 
    Log[x + 3] + Log[Sqrt[2 x^2 + 2 x]] /. x -> 1
```

> `True`

Also the command:

```
    Reduce[6*Log[(Sqrt[2 x] + Sqrt[x + 1] + 4*Surd[x + 3, 4])/6] == 
    Log[x + 3] + Log[Sqrt[2 x^2 + 2 x]], x, Reals]
```

is running without any response on my comp for more than 8 hours.
I think it's going into an infinite loop.

The answer `x==1` implies Jensen's  inequality
(see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)).

What is the reason for such behavior of `NSolve`?

Comment: `FindRoot[
 6*Log[(Sqrt[2 x] + Sqrt[x + 1] + 4*Surd[x + 3, 4])/6] - Log[x + 3] - 
  Log[Sqrt[2 x^2 + 2 x]], {x, 2}]` performs `{x -> 1.}`.

Comment: Windows Task Manager shows high CPU usage, periodic reads from SSD, Alt . does not stop the execution. Endless loop,. Since the plot of the difference shows the minimum at x=1 and singularity at x=-3, its a Solve bug.  At least I was happy that copy of running notebook and paste text to a new one is working  now in 13.2

Comment: @RolandF: You wrote "Since the plot of the difference shows the minimum at x=1 and singularity at x=-3". How do you plot complex values?

Comment: `NSolve[6*Log[(Sqrt[2 x] + Sqrt[x + 1] + 4*Power[x + 3, 1/4])/6] == Log[x + 3] + Log[Sqrt[2 x^2 + 2 x]] && (x >= 0 && x <= 2 || x > 2 && x <= 10), x, Reals]`

Comment: @Coofy: Thank you. Works. I think due to `Power`.  However,  `Reduce[6*Log[(Sqrt[2 x] + Sqrt[x + 1] + 4*Power[x + 3, 1/4])/6] == 
   Log[x + 3] + Log[Sqrt[2 x^2 + 2 x]] && (x >= 0 && x <= 2 || 
    x > 2 && x <= 10), x, Reals]`  is still running forever.

Comment: "Since I cannot contact [support].." - why can't you?

Comment: @MarcoB: I saw "Server is not accessible". Now I can contact and I have submitted a bug.

Comment: `NSolve[6*Log[(Sqrt[2 x] + Sqrt[x + 1] + 4*Surd[x + 3, 4])/6] == Log[x + 3] + Log[Sqrt[2 x^2 + 2 x]] && (x >= 0 && x <= 2 || x > 2 && x <= 10), x]` works for me, but more slowly. `Reals` is redundant, causes extra checking, limits techniques that may be applied. `NSolve` first solved only systems that can be transformed into polynomial form. Then some enhancement to complex-analytic and real-analytic. Plus incremental improvements. It still cannot solve everything. Strongest on complex-analytic on a bounded domain. Hence `Power`, not `Surd`; and no `Reals`. But `Surd` works without `Reals`.

Comment: @Goofy: Thank you. Can you ground your "`Reals` is redundant"? There is a chance that `NSolve` uses some different algorithm in complex domain.

Comment: Surd tries to select the real root. Suspect NSolve is not ready to cope with it numerically  @64494 : I always Plot ReIM toegeter, by inspection -Log[x+3] has a branch point at x=-3. Another difficulty: the zero is quadratic at 1.0 , as

NSolve[(D[
      6 Log[(Sqrt[2 x] + Sqrt[x + 1] + 4*Surd[x + 3, 4])/6] - 
       Log[x + 3] - Log[Sqrt[2 x^2 + 2 x]], x] // Together // 
    Numerator) == 0]

Comment: @Goofy: BTW, the result of `ComplexPlot3D[
 6*Log[(Sqrt[2 x] + Sqrt[x + 1] + 4*(x + 3)^(1/4))/6] - Log[x + 3] - 
  Log[Sqrt[2 x^2 + 2 x]], {x, -3 - 5*I, 5 + 5*I}, PlotPoints -> 50]` is strange.

Comment: @Goofy: `NSolve[6*Log[(Sqrt[2 x]+Sqrt[x+1]+4*(x+3)^(1/4))/6]==Log[x+3]+Log[Sqrt[2 x^2+2 x]]&&(x>=0&&x<=10),x]` also produces `{}`.

Comment: Maybe I missed something? And the logs and powers are not real when 0 < x < 10? In a code sense, `Reals` is not redundant in that it changes what algorithms `NSolve` will try, the evidence being the different results.

Comment: @Goofy: Can you explain the difference between  'NSolve[6*Log[(Sqrt[2 x] + Sqrt[x + 1] + 4*(x + 3)^(1/4))/6] == 
   Log[x + 3] + Log[Sqrt[2 x^2 + 2 x]] && (x >= 0 && x <= 2 || 
    x > 2 && x <= 10), x]' which outputs `{{x -> 1.}}` and `NSolve[6*Log[(Sqrt[2 x]+Sqrt[x+1]+4*(x+3)^(1/4))/6]==Log[x+3]+Log[Sqrt[2 x^2+2 x]]&&(x>=0&&x<=10),x]` which results in `{}` (the same with `Reals` option)?

Comment: `Solve` works for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"];
```

As a workaround, reformulate the problem as a numeric minimization

```
expr = 6*Log[(Sqrt[2 x] + Sqrt[x + 1] + 4*Surd[x + 3, 4])/6] - (Log[x + 3] + 
     Log[Sqrt[2 x^2 + 2 x]]);

{nmin, narg} = NMinimize[{expr^2, 0 < x < 10}, x, WorkingPrecision -> 25]

(* {0, {x -> 0.9999999999988542055148064}} *)

expr /. narg

(* 0.*10^-25 *)
```

Since the approximate numeric result is close to an integer, try

```
{min, arg} = Minimize[{expr^2, 0 < x < 10}, x, Integers] // Simplify

(* {0, {x -> 1}} *)
```

**EDIT:** With [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html), use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
eqn = 6*Log[(Sqrt[2 x] + Sqrt[x + 1] + 4*Surd[x + 3, 4])/6] == 
  Log[x + 3] + Log[Sqrt[2 x^2 + 2 x]]

NSolve[{eqn // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &, 
  0 < x < 10}, x]

(* NSolve::nongen: - Message text not found --

{{x -> 1.}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for  workarounds. However, the behaviors of `NSolve` and `Reduce`  for the equation under consideration leave much  to be desired.

Comment: I can't reproduce `expr = 6*
    Log[(Sqrt[2 x] + Sqrt[x + 1] + 4*Surd[x + 3, 4])/6] - (Log[
      x + 3] + Log[Sqrt[2 x^2 + 2 x]]);
Minimize[{expr^2, 0 < x < 10}, x, Integers]` on Windows 10 during  a dozen 
 minutes.

Comment: For `RepeatedTiming[{min, arg} = Minimize[{expr^2, 0 < x < 10}, x, Integers] // Simplify]` I get `{0.0160447, {0, {x -> 1}}}`

Comment: So there is a difference between Mathematica on Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) and Windows 10 here. I still can't reproduce `Minimize[{expr^2, 0 < x < 10}, x, Integers]`  on Windows 10.

Comment: +1. Thank you for your edit. Works on Windows 10. I find it interesting and important . Here is the result of `ComplexExpand`:

Comment: `6 I ArcTan[ Sqrt[2] (x^2)^(1/4) Cos[1/2 ArcTan[x, 0]] + ((1 + x)^2)^(1/4)
       Cos[1/2 ArcTan[1 + x, 0]] + 4 Surd[3 + x, 4],  Sqrt[2] (x^2)^(1/4) Sin[1/2 ArcTan[x, 0]] + ((1 + x)^2)^(1/4) Sin[1/2 ArcTan[1 + x, 0]]] - 6 Log[6] + 
  6 Log[\[Sqrt]((Sqrt[2] (x^2)^(1/4) Sin[1/2 ArcTan[x, 0]] + ((1 + x)^2)^(1/4)
           Sin[1/2 ArcTan[1 + x, 0]])^2 + (Sqrt[2] (x^2)^(1/4)
           Cos[1/2 ArcTan[x, 0]] + ((1 + x)^2)^(1/4)Cos[1/2 ArcTan[1 + x, 0]] + 4 Surd[3 + x, 4])^2)] == 
 I (ArcTan[3 + x, 0] + 1/2 ArcTan[2 x + 2 x^2, 0]) + 
  1/2 Log[(3 + x)^2] + 1/4 Log[(2 x + 2 x^2)^2]`

Comment: I think `NSolve` uses some different algorithm in the complex domain.